# Installutil keeps telling me "No public installers found". Any ideas?

Tags: windows-services, installutil

I am trying to install a Windows service just created in Visual Studio 2008. The Install.log file tells me the following again and again:

```
No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the [correct path to my assembly] assembly.
```

My service has an installer "serviceInstaller1" which is Public and has the correct service name. It also has a serviceProcessInstaller1 that is also Public.

Why can't InstallUtil find the installer in my service assembly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Turns out everything works when the service.exe is on the C drive.